# Code from dev-c++ don't work on visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, bitmap, dev-c++

i'm writing a little game with c++ and SFML and i got stuck at generating a maze to be exact, so i found on internet few codes and adjusted to my need and created a maze to .bmp file. Now i want to read it in program and change it to fit my map and save into file named level.map. In bitmap reader I based on some codes from internet and it works well, but only on dev-c++ 5.11 (64-bit and 32-bit release) but when i compiling it on visual studio 2013, its reads 0 value everywhere, instead of mixing 1 and 0.

My code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;
struct FileHeader {
    short bfType;
    int bfSize;
    short bfReserved1;
    short bfReserved2;
    short bfOffBits;
};
FileHeader File;

struct PictureHeader {
    int biSize;
    int biWidth;
    int biHeight;
    short biPlanes;
    short biBitCount;
    int biCompression;
    int biSizeImage;
    int biXPelsPerMeter;
    int biYPelsPerMeter;
    int biClrUsed;
    int biClrImportant;
};
PictureHeader Picture;

struct RGBcolors {
    char R;
    char G;
    char B;
};
RGBcolors Rgb;
char dane;
string str;
string bottom = "111111111111111111111111111111111";
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {


    FILE *f = fopen("Maze.bmp", "rb");

    system("cls");
    printf("\n Info about BITMAP\n\n");

    fread(&File.bfType, sizeof(File.bfType), 1, f);
    printf(" Typ: %x", File.bfType);

    fread(&File.bfSize, sizeof(File.bfSize), 1, f);
    printf("\n Size of file: %d bytes", File.bfSize);

    fread(&File.bfReserved1, sizeof(File.bfReserved1), 1, f);
    printf("\n Reserved2: %d", File.bfReserved1);

    fread(&File.bfReserved2, sizeof(File.bfReserved2), 1, f);
    printf("\n Reserved2: %d", File.bfReserved2);

    fread(&File.bfOffBits, sizeof(File.bfOffBits), 1, f);

    printf("\n");

    fseek(f, 14, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&Picture.biSize, sizeof(Picture.biSize), 1, f);
    printf("\n Size of header: %d", Picture.biSize);

    fread(&Picture.biWidth, sizeof(Picture.biWidth), 1, f);
    printf("\n Width: %d px", Picture.biWidth);

    fread(&Picture.biHeight, sizeof(Picture.biHeight), 1, f);
    printf("\n Heigh: %d px", Picture.biHeight);

    fread(&Picture.biPlanes, sizeof(Picture.biPlanes), 1, f);

    fread(&Picture.biBitCount, sizeof(Picture.biBitCount), 1, f);
    printf("\n Bits per pixel: %d (1, 4, 8, or 24)", Picture.biBitCount);

    fread(&Picture.biCompression, sizeof(Picture.biCompression), 1, f);
    printf("\n Compression: %d (0=none, 1=RLE-8, 2=RLE-4)", Picture.biCompression);

    fread(&Picture.biSizeImage, sizeof(Picture.biSizeImage), 1, f);
    printf("\n Size of only a image: %d", Picture.biSizeImage);

    fread(&Picture.biXPelsPerMeter, sizeof(Picture.biXPelsPerMeter), 1, f);
    fread(&Picture.biYPelsPerMeter, sizeof(Picture.biYPelsPerMeter), 1, f);
    fread(&Picture.biClrUsed, sizeof(Picture.biClrUsed), 1, f);
    fread(&Picture.biClrImportant, sizeof(Picture.biClrImportant), 1, f);


    fseek(f, File.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);
    cout << "\n\n\n Structure:\n";


    int bmpImg;

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = File.bfOffBits; i < File.bfSize; i++)
    {

        fseek(f, i, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&bmpImg, 1, 1, f);
        if ((i - File.bfOffBits) % 96 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            if (i != File.bfOffBits)
                str += "1\n";
            c++;
        }
        if ((i - File.bfOffBits) % 3 == 0) {
            printf("%d", (bmpImg == 255 ? 1 : 0));
            str += (bmpImg == 255 ? "1" : "0");
        }

    }
    printf("\n");

    fclose(f);
    str += "1\n";
    str += bottom;

    {

    }
    if (str.length() > 1)
    {
        FILE *plik = fopen("maze.map", "w");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            fprintf(plik, "%c", str[i]);
        }


        fclose(plik);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Bitmap is 32x32 size.
E.g. [image: generated maze]

Correct result from dev-c++
[image]

And incorrect result from visual studio:
[image]

Appreciate any advices and directions

Comment: You don't check if `fopen` succeeds. Perhaps the current directory isn't the one you expect.

Comment: but fopen i succeded in both to read a header of bmp file, like on screens type, size, size of header, width, height etc are the same, only when i read pixels it diffrents

Comment: Hmm. Try stepping over the code in both IDEs until the variables don't match. Then you'll have a much better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Did like you suggest @Cameron, visual studio have problem in `fread(&bmpImg, 1, 1, f)`, VS didn't read any values there and leave memory trash what was left in that variable.

Comment: Alright then, that gives us somewhere to start. What does fread return? Does the call to fopen succeed? Does the call to fseek succeed?

Comment: already working, i don't know why, but when i initialize bmpImg, variable to where i read from fread, its working. doesnt matter what value, dunno why but key is to initialize that variable.

Comment: And thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds like there's undefined behaviour somewhere. If you crank up the warning level, does anything turn up?

Comment: turned warning level 4 still wrong result if bmpImg not initialized, same for allwarnings

Comment: If you found the answer, write an answer. Solutions do not go in questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Just initialized with any value variable where i was reading to from fread.